# Error [dcc32 Fatal Error] F2084 Internal Error: AV06028036(05FB0000)-R2CD489B0-0

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I know that probably if i recreate my project this error will get away, but i wish to know why this happens. Could someone explain me?

I am using Delphi 10.4. I was testing this project without saving it, but i saved and it keeps happening. I just want to understand why this happens.

My code:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Memo.Types, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Memo,
  FMX.StdCtrls;//, Winapi.Windows;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    memSource: TMemo;
    memDest: TMemo;
    btnInfo: TSpeedButton;
    btnMai: TSpeedButton;
    btnCript: TSpeedButton;
    btnMin: TSpeedButton;
    procedure trataTexto(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.trataTexto(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: AnsiString;
  i,cont: Integer;
  palavra, agora: boolean;
begin
  S := memSource.Text;
  if btnInfo.isPressed then
  begin
    palavra := False;
    cont := 0;
    for i := 1 to Length(S) do
    begin
      agora := upcase(BestFit(S[i])[1]) in ['A'..'Z', '-'];
      if palavra <> agora then
      begin
        if agora then
          inc(cont);
        palavra := agora;
      end;
    end;
    memDest.Text := format('%d caracteres'#10'%d palavras', [
      Length(S),cont
    ]);
  end else
  if btnMai.isPressed then
  begin
    memDest.Text := Uppercase(S);
  end else
  if btnMin.isPressed then
  begin
    memDest.Text := Lowercase(S);
  end else
  if btnCript.isPressed then
  begin
    S := uppercase(S);
    for i := 1 to Length(S) do
      if S[i] in ['A'..'Z'] then
        S[i] := S[i];
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: It's a bug in the compiler. Not much more we can say about it.

Comment: Did you try to use "Clean"?

Comment: Or "Build" (Shift+F9).

Comment: Is this reproducible? If it is, create a report at https://quality.embarcadero.com

Comment: FWIW that looks like a pretty inefficient way to count characters in a string list.

Comment: I was counting words... No, it is not easily reproducible.